# Testing sails controller

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to test my sails controller. But when i am using this line of code in my UserController.test.js, its throwing an error **cannot call address of undefined**

```
var app = sails.hooks.http.app
```

in bootstrap.test.js , I have declared the sails like this

```
var sails = require('sails')
before(function(done){
   Sails.lift({},function(err,sails){
      done(err, sails);
   })
})
```

PS: I have checked that sails.hooks is working fine, only on calling http method its giving me that error.

I am following [this](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing) link for testing.
[sails testing](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Testing)

Comment: what sails version is this in?

Comment: @TravisWebb sails version: 0.9.16

Comment: From your code it isn't clear if you are storing a reference to sails anywhere. Can you paste some more code?

Comment: Check my sails.js test example: [https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example](https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example) It show how to test a sails.js v0.10.x project request and may work with latest versions

Answer (score 0):

first you should conf inside the sails.lift, things as:

```
 models: {
        connection: 'test',
        migrate: 'drop'
      }
```

there are example: https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example